# Yii using relational attributes in form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

In my Yii application  I have two tables called "producer_offer" and "book_vegetable". I have a column called "book_vegetable_id" in producer_offer table which is a foreign key of the primary key column "id" of "producer_offer" table.

Now I want to refer to a  column called "booked_quantity" of "book_vegetable" table inside  "producer_offer" table.
I want to refer to this column in the  view form .
My  code  for relation function in  "producer_offer" table .

```
public function relations()
    {
 'producerOfferBookVegetable'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'BookVegetable','book_vegetable_id')
        );
    }
```

In the form I want to enter the value of "booked_quantity" of  "book_vegetable" table.
How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I think is that what you are trying to do:

Controller.php

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $modelBV=new BookVegetable;
    $modelPO=new ProducerOffer;

    if(isset($_POST['BookVegetable']) AND isset($_POST['ProducerOffer'])) {

        $modelBV->attributes=$_POST['BookVegetable'];
        $modelPO->attributes=$_POST['ProducerOffer'];
        if($modelBV->validate()  AND  $modelPO->validate()) {
            $modelBV->save()

            $modelPO->book_vegetable_id = $modelBV->id;
            $modelPO->save();
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'modelBV'=>$modelBV,
        'modelPO'=>$modelPO,
    ));
}
```

---

Or you could use an extension like:
https://github.com/yiiext/with-related-behavior

Comment: I don't want to show the records in the view. I want to create a record of 'book_vegetable' in the 'producer_offer' table .That is .. in the form of producer_offer table,  there should be an attribute for 'booked_quantity' of 'book_vegetable' and that record should be 'booked_quantity' should be stored in the 'book_vegetable' table.